# Python: Importing modules and libraries

Tags: python-3.x

Whats the difference between the following statements:

1. `import os`
2. `from os import *`

Do they mean one and the same thing? If so, why two ways of saying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import os`

brings the name os into the namespace and thus the os name becomes unique.

so using `os.read(fd, n)` will read n bytes from the file descriptor fd.

`from os import *`

brings all the names from the module os into the global namespace. Thus we can use `read(fd,n)` directly.

Problem with `from os import *` :

If we have our own function read(fd,n) in the local namespace, by using `from os import *` we get 2 functions with the same name, and the interpreter uses the local function with that name.

If we create a module with a read(fd,n) function having the same name as the one in os module (both function names will be in the global namespace), the interpreter will only use one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`from os import *` imports all methods from os, and should be avoided.

`import os` just import the namespace and allows you to call methods from `os` by prefixing with `os.`